# is this possible as an XSS exploit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm working through some legacy apps and curious whether this would be a viable XSS exploit?

code:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<script src="/me.js"></script>';
</script>
```

I don't think so but there's smarter people out there than me. Is there a variation of this?

Comment: What part of this is XSS?

Comment: Setting `.innerHTML` does not load/execute included `<script>` blocks. (You could try this yourself to verify.)

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Did you run it? Seems like an easy test case. But setting innerHTML can easily add plenty of other XSS opportunities.

Comment: @Pointy But setting of the innerhtml would be a valid entry for xss: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.google.se/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' onload='alert(1)'>";`

Comment: @E.Sundin what you're suggesting is *completely different* from what the OP asked.

Comment: it's a yes or no question lol

Answer (score 0):

This in itself is harmless:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<script src="/me.js"></script>';
```

> HTML5 specifies that a  tag inserted with innerHTML should not execute. <sup>1</sup>

However (and since you're asking), there may be a remote chance (admittedly) that this could still be exploited:

```js
// This is the backdoor that an attacker has to inject somehow
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
  set: function (value) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = `alert('gotcha! ${value}')`;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
});

// This is what you're doing in your app
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<script src="/me.js"><\/script>';
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

As you can see it'd be easy to parse and extract the url and re-inject the script into the page.

---

Nowadays, using `innerHTML` is most likely going to be discouraged. Example:

> Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process. <sup>1</sup>

React has an interesting way (IMHO) to discourage you from using it:

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. <sup>2</sup>

---

Finally, I think it's worth mentioning that both epascarello and E. Sundin have a valid point. We know that `<script>` won't load and/or execute when injected via `innerHTML` but it doesn't mean that you're safe:

```html
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML =
  '<img src="x.gif" onerror="alert(42)">';
</script>
```

**References**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations
2. https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml